# how to export environment variable with space in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, export

when I export the environment variable :

```
$ export VS_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/bla/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2010/Projects/
```

and echo $VS_PATH gives the correct variable,

```
$ echo $VS_PATH
/cygdrive/c/Users/bla/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/
```

so I thought it is set correctly.But

```
$ cd $VS_PATH
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Users/bla/Documents/Visual: No such file or directory
```

what is the problem? How could I export and cd it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `cd` command is reading the variable as is, meaning the exact same way you see it when you `echo` it. It'll work fine if you put the var in quote marks.

`$ cd "$VS_PATH"`